# Helper handlebars me multiplica el section donde renderizar la data

Tags: javascript, handlebars

Este helper nos renderiza los campos que queremos, pero nos esta multiplicando por 5 el section.

Probamos con el helper #with, pero no nos devuelve el objeto correctamente como queremos, nos devuelve el objeto entero por cada campo

```
<section>
        {{#each car}}
            <dt>Marca:</dt><dd>{{carBrand}}</dd>
            <dt>Modelo:</dt><dd>{{carModel}}</dd>
            <dt>Fecha de recogida:</dt><dd>{{leaseDate}}</dd>
            <dt>Fecha de devolución:</dt><dd>{{leaseReturnDate}}</dd>
            <dt>Importe:</dt><dd>{{finalPrice}} &euro;</dd>
        {{/each}}
</section>
```

Esto es lo que nos imprime, como veis en el ultimo bucle imprime la data, pero antes nos genera 5 sections mas

```
Marca:
Modelo:
Fecha de recogida:
Fecha de devolución:
Importe:
€
Marca:
Modelo:
Fecha de recogida:
Fecha de devolución:
Importe:
€
Marca:
Modelo:
Fecha de recogida:
Fecha de devolución:
Importe:
€
Marca:
Modelo:
Fecha de recogida:
Fecha de devolución:
Importe:
€
Marca:
Modelo:
Fecha de recogida:
Fecha de devolución:
Importe:
€
Marca:
Ford
Modelo:
Kuga
Fecha de recogida:
Sat Mar 06 2021 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (hora estándar de Europa central)
Fecha de devolución:
Tue Mar 09 2021 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (hora estándar de Europa central)
Importe:
99 €
```

Aqui os compartimos el objeto

```
{
  _id: 60421de0f35ac42194a490b9,      
  carBrand: 'Ford',
  carModel: 'Kuga',
  leasingPrice: 99,
  leaseDate: 2021-03-06T00:00:00.000Z,
  leaseReturnDate: 2021-03-09T00:00:00.000Z,
  carId: '604210d45c921026844e11b9',
  __v: 0
}
```

Aqui os dejo el codigo del controlador.
Nuestra idea es traer solo un objeto y que inmediatamente despues de guardar el nuevo alquiler nos imprima en otra vista los datos almacenados.
Es por ese el hecho que comenta el compañero que nos facilitó la respuesta de que le estamos pasando un objeto y no un array y por eso no itera cada propiedad.
Nuestra idea es mantener esta función y no hacer otra aparte para buscar un array en la base de datos por su id.

```
'use strict';

const {getSingleCar, carUpdate} = require('./carControllerFunct');
const {rentUpdate} = require('./rentControllerFunct');
const Rent = require('../models/Rent');

const RentController = {};

RentController.leaseCar = async (req, res) => {
    const singleCar = await getSingleCar(req.params.id);
    const Ndays = (new Date((req.body.leaseReturnDate)).getTime() - new Date((req.body.leaseDate)).getTime())/(24*60*60*1000);
    console.log(Ndays);
    const finalPrice = (singleCar.leasingPrice*Ndays);
    const newRent = new Rent ({
        carBrand: singleCar.carBrand,
        carModel: singleCar.carModel,
        leasingPrice: finalPrice,
        leaseDate: req.body.leaseDate,
        leaseReturnDate: req.body.leaseReturnDate,
        carId: singleCar._id
    });
       
    const car = await newRent.save();

    res.render("rent/rentDetailTemplate", {car});
};

RentController.showAllRents = async (req,res) => {
    const rentsList = await Rent.find().lean();
    rentUpdate(rentsList);
    res.render("rent/allRents", {rents: rentsList} );
};

module.exports = RentController;
```

Comment: ¿Podrías [edit] tu pregunta y agregar un [mcve]?

Comment: Espero que te sirva lo que acabo de aportar. Es el controlador donde ejecutamos la funcion crear un nuevo alquiler, guardarlo e inmediatamente coger esa data e imprimirla en una vista.

Comment: ¿Que hace la función `rentUpdate(rentsList)`? Se me occure el que problema esta en el contenido de la variable `rentsList` o lo que la función `rentUpdate` le hace a dicha variable

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta. El problema venia de que estabamos recibiendo un objeto y no un array, por eso el helper no recorría los parametros correctamente.

Answer (score 1):

Me da la sensación de que estáis pasando mal los coches al template:

```js
const car = {
  _id: '60421de0f35ac42194a490b9',      
  carBrand: 'Ford',
  carModel: 'Kuga',
  leasingPrice: 99,
  leaseDate: '2021-03-06T00:00:00.000Z',
  leaseReturnDate: '2021-03-09T00:00:00.000Z',
  carId: '604210d45c921026844e11b9',
  __v: 0
};

const source = document.getElementById("entry-template").innerHTML;
const template = Handlebars.compile(source);


let html = template({car: [car]});
console.log('con un array de coches', html);

document.getElementById('wrap').innerHTML = html;

html = template({car});
console.log('con un coche como objeto', html);

document.getElementById('wrap').innerHTML += '<hr/>' + html;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.7.7/handlebars.min.js" integrity="sha512-RNLkV3d+aLtfcpEyFG8jRbnWHxUqVZozacROI4J2F1sTaDqo1dPQYs01OMi1t1w9Y2FdbSCDSQ2ZVdAC8bzgAg==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script id="entry-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
  <section>
    {{#each car}}
    {{this}}
        <dt>Marca:</dt><dd>{{carBrand}}</dd>
        <dt>Modelo:</dt><dd>{{carModel}}</dd>
        <dt>Fecha de recogida:</dt><dd>{{leaseDate}}</dd>
        <dt>Fecha de devolución:</dt><dd>{{leaseReturnDate}}</dd>
        <dt>Importe:</dt><dd>{{finalPrice}} &euro;</dd>
    {{/each}}
  </section>
</script>

<div id="wrap"><div>
```

Si le pasas un array de coches, el template itera por cada elemento. Si le pasas un único elemento, *creo* que itera por sus propiedades.

Comment: Ni idea, la verdad, pero he editado mi respuesta para mostrar el valor del item sobre el que se itera y efectivamente es cada una de las propiedades.

Comment: Creo que tienes toda la razon en que le pasamos un objeto y por eso no itera, en esa parte nos aclaraste el error, nos gustaría mantener la idea y seguir desde ese objeto, nuestra intencion es que una vez hayamos guardado el nuevo alquiler, nos renderice esa data en una vista. Sabemos hacerlo desde otra función llamando al array de datos en la bbdd e iterando el objeto en cuestion, pero habría que traerlo por su id. Queriamos poder hacerlo de esta manera

Comment: Por cierto, añadí el controlador a la pregunta para poder verlo